# Calculator HTML

Tags: html, css, calculator

I'm having problem with the height, margin and align. I would like to align my calculator to the middle, reposition my "C" button close to other buttons, and customize the height of the "=" equal button without affecting other buttons.

1. How do I customize the height of my "=" button without affecting other buttons?
2. My "C" button, I want it to be close to the other buttons.
3. I would like to align the calculator at the centre.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7b4397, #dc2430);
}

input[type=button] {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border: color: none;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: ;
  margin-bottom: inherit;
  width: 140px;
  height: 42px;
}

#del {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form name="Calculator">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <input type="text" name="Answer"> <input type="button" value="C" name="Delete" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = ' ' ">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '+' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '-' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '/' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '*' "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '7' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '8' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '9' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="=" id="del" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = eval(Calculator.Answer.value) "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '4' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '5' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '6' "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '1' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '2' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '3' "></td>
    </tr>

    <table>

</form>
```

[image: The result]

Comment: I made a calculator in HTML once, and I ended up having to giving each of the buttons `position:absolute` and their own `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The important thing about the '=' button is to use `rowspan` on its `td` element.
2. I added `td` elements (one with `colspan`) and slightly adapted the existing `CSS` to reposition the 'C' button.
3. Centering the calculator can be done using `CSS flexbox layout`.

See the result below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>   
    body {
        background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, #7b4397 ,#dc2430 );
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    div {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {        
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: -6px;
        margin-top: -6px;
        border: 
        color: none;
    }    
    
    input[type=text] {
        font-family: cursive;
        margin-top: ;
        margin-bottom: inherit;
        width: 140px;
        height: 42px;        
        margin-right: -6px;
        margin-top: -6px;
    }

    #del {
        height:150px;
    }    
</style>

<body>
  <div>
 <form name="Calculator">        
  <table>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Answer"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="C" name="Delete" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = ' ' "></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '+' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '-' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '/' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '*' "></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '7' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '8' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '9' "></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="=" id="del" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = eval(Calculator.Answer.value) "></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '4' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '5' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '6' "></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '1' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '2' "></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '3' "></td>
   </tr>            
  <table>         
 </form>
  </div> 
</body>        
</html>
```

Comment: The C button is not close to the other buttons like this https://imgur.com/a/DzNGN5r

Comment: Had to add missing `td` elements and slightly change the existing `CSS`, please have a look.

Comment: i didnt see sry

Comment: https://codepen.io/YosuaM/pen/oNgzaEp l How do i center the calculator?

Comment: If you run my code snipped, you'll see that it is centered. This is mainly done using `CSS flexbox layout`.

Comment: Oh i see i didnt add that

Comment: Thanks for that problem i would like to ask 1 more time. https://codepen.io/YosuaM/pen/oNgzaEp. (this is the code) . The 1st problem is the bottom left button, i cant make it round like the other buttons. https://imgur.com/a/YHg4DPi. 2nd problem is a spacing problem https://imgur.com/a/9Yy81uj,  i want it no space.

Comment: @YosuaM: Please post new questions for new issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` to control the merged cells. I strongly suggest using `display: grid` instead of HTML tables.

Instead of controlling the `<input>` sizes you should set the `<td>` width and height and let the child's follow the cascade.

```css
html, body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input[type=button] {
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<form name="Calculator">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Answer"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="C" name="Delete" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = ' ' "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '+' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '-' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '/' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '*' "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '7' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '8' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '9' "></td>
      <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="=" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value = eval(Calculator.Answer.value) "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '4' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '5' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '6' "></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '1' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '2' "></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="Calculator.Answer.value += '3' "></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</form>
```